# Keeping unused files in Xcode project

Tags: xcode

In Eclipse you can create a folder and name it, say, "unused", to keep currently unused files (incomplete code, resources for future use, etc)
which are ignored by project builder. Can I have something similar with Xcode?

If I move a file to a project folder without inserting it with Xcode, it may be OK, and I will be able to see it while opening in Finder. However, it will be more convenient to have it listed by Project Navigator.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As far as I am concerned, it's not possible. Though, you can comment all of your code in one click to momentarily disable it.

1. Press <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>;
2. Right click and select <kbd>Comment Selection</kbd>.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know about this feature in Xcode.